# Using self-referential generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following Java method:

```
<T extends List<T>> List<T> getMyList() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

I can assign its output to a variable with a raw type, like so:

```
List x = getMyList();
List<List> y = getMyList();
```

But, I can't think of any way to assign its output to a fully parameterized type. In particular, I can't think of a non-raw, concrete type `T` that would satisfy `List<T> z = getMyList();`

Can we create such a `T` ?
If not, why not?

*For context, I created this question while trying to understand how Enums are implemented in Java.*

Comment: Please feel free to suggest an alternative title for this question if it gets the idea across more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a concrete type that both works and starts to hint at a possible use-case (registration of some sort). The type consists acts like both an instance of some type, and as a container for all instances of that type.

```
public class WeirdEnum extends AbstractList<WeirdEnum> {

  private static List<WeirdEnum> underlyingList = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public WeirdEnum get(int index) { return underlyingList.get(index); }

  @Override
  public int size() { return underlyingList.size(); }

  static <T extends List<T>> List<T> getAList() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  public WeirdEnum() {
    underlyingList.add(this); // Sufficient for our example but not a good idea due to concurrency concerns.
  }

  static List<WeirdEnum> foo = WeirdEnum.getAList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but here's an example:

```java
class Example<T> implements List<Example<T>> {
...
}
...
List<Example<String>> list = getMyList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every enum in Java extends from the base-enum-class `Enum<T extends Enum<T>>`, where `T` is the actual type of the implementing enum.

When writing `SomeClass<T extends SomeClass<T>>` you can enforce that the type-parameter is always the implementing class itself.

Let's say you have this interface:

```java
public interface MyInterface<T extends MyInterface<T>> {

    T getSelf();
}
```

And this implementing class:

```java
public class MyClass implements MyInterface<MyClass> {

    public MyClass getSelf() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

In `MyClass` it is not possible to use any other type-parameter than `MyClass` itself.